# Need some help regarding combining two classes

Tags: c#, wpf

Before I get started, I just want to say I'm still in the learning phase of `C#`, please have mercy on my soul.

Any-who, I'm busy currently writing a simplistic program with Visual Studio Code (`WPF`).

Here's my code that's giving me a headache:

```
using System;


    public Window3()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        // INIT FIRST ANIMAL.

        string name = "Spotty";
        int age = 6;
        float happiness = 0.5f;
        string animal_type = "Dog";

        // NUMBER OF ANIMALS INIT VAR.

        int Count = 0;

        Count++;

        // FIRST ANIMAL EXAMPLE.

        Test.Content = "Name: " + name + "\n" + "Age: " + age + "\n" + "Happiness: " + happiness + "\n" + "Animal Type: " + animal_type;

        Test1.Content = AnimalList("idk", 10, 0.5f, "idk");

        Count++;

        //Test2.Content = "";



        // LIST NUMBER OF ANIMALS FUNCTION.

        Test3.Content = "Number of Animals: " + Count;
    }


    public static int Count { get; private set; }
        public static string name { get; private set; }
        public static int age { get; private set; }
        public static float happiness { get; private set; }
        public static string animal_type { get; private set; }

        public static string AnimalList(string _name, int _age, float _happiness, string _animal_type)
    {
        name = _name;
        age =  _age;
        happiness = _happiness;
        animal_type = _animal_type;

        return name + age + happiness + animal_type;
    }

    public void Print() 
    {

        Test1.Content = "Name: " + name + "\n" + "Age: " + age + "\n";

    }

}
```

Now to elaborate regarding my problem.

I want `Test1.Content = AnimalList("idk", 10, 0.5f, "idk");` to work with

```
public void Print() 
    {

        Test1.Content = "Name: " + name + "\n" + "Age: " + age + "\n";

    }
```

How can I make that possible? Because I want it to display like this inside a label:

> Name: idk
>
> Age: 10
>
> Happiness: 0.5
>
> Type of Animal: idk

I'll really appreciate any help.

Comment: "a simplistic program" - many things here are actually unnecessary complicated

Comment: @ASh I know right. I'm just mostly using this program to experiment and for learning purposes. Like I stated I'm still new to C# lol.

Comment: Maybe it's a good idea to format and fix above code. It does not compile. There is something missing. You cannot do `Count++; ` just anywhere in a class and the class scope is finished prematurely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want Test1.Content = AnimalList("idk", 10, 0.5f, "idk"); to work with

```
public string AnimalList(string _name, int _age, float _happiness, string _animal_type)
{
    name = _name;
    age =  _age;
    happiness = _happiness;
    animal_type = _animal_type;

    return name + age + happiness + animal_type;
}
```

The main issue I can see is that `AnimalList` isn't static, the signature needs to be changed to:

```
 public static string AnimalList(string _name, int _age, float _happiness, string _animal_type)
```

*The reason for this is because there's no instance as the fields you're using are all static.

On another note, there's much in your current approach that could be cleaned up to make things a little easier for you to work with.

**Here's one approach you can work with:**

1. Create a new class to hold an animals properties.
2. Use a `List<Animal>` to hold animals you add/create.

**Animal Class:**

```
 public class Animal
 {
    #region | Enums |

    public enum AnimalType
    {
        Dog = 0,
        Cat = 1,
    }

    #endregion

    #region | Properties |

    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public int Age { get; set; } = 0;

    public float Happiness { get; set; } = 0f;

    public AnimalType Animaltype { get; set; } = AnimalType.Dog;

    #endregion

    #region | Constructor |

    public Animal(string name, int age, float happiness, AnimalType animalType)
    {
        Name = name;
        Age = age;
        Happiness = happiness;
        Animaltype = animalType;
    }

    #endregion

    #region | Overrides |

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name + Environment.NewLine + Age.ToString() + Environment.NewLine + Happiness.ToString() + Environment.NewLine() + Animaltype.ToString();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

**Add a new field to hold these Animal's:**

```
 public List<Animal> AnimalList = new List<Animal>();
```

**After `InitializeComponent()` add:**

```
 // Add a new animal to the list
 AnimalList.Add(new Animal("Spotty", 6, 0.5f, Animal.AnimalType.Dog));
 // Print the first animal out
 Print();
```

**Print Routine:**

```
 public void Print()
 {
     Test1.Content = AnimalList[0].ToString();
 }
```

If you want a count of animals, you can now just call:

```
 AnimalList.Count();
```

Comment: Thank you so much Codexer! I just implemented your way and it works way better. You're an absolute legend and genius. Thanks a bunch for all your help, I really appreciate it!